Can I add common fields to different struct definitions in rust?
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: String,
    pub username: String,
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "accountGroupId", deserialize = "accountGroupId"))]
    pub account_group_id: String,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: String,
    pub contact: String,
}

We need to add common fields such like "enable" to User & Client. Then we can use like this
let user = User {
    id: "user-id-value",
    enable: true,
}

let client = Client {
    id: "client-id-value",
    enable: true,
}


Trait is NOT what we want because it only supports method. Then we have to call something like user.enable() instead of user.enable.
Nested field is also NOT what we want because we have to access something like user.base.enable instead of user.enable.
Looks like we can do this by attribute marco which we can add common fields and create a new struct. But don't know how to implement it.
#[user_base]
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: String,
    pub username: String,
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "accountGroupId", deserialize = "accountGroupId"))]
    pub account_group_id: String,
}

#[user_base]
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: String,
    pub contact: String,
}

Any help would be appreciated.

"There is nothing that exactly matches that"

That is what declarative macros are for. Although given this seems to be some sort of communication schema, using nested objects to share a common header would likely make a lot more sense (declarative macros still being an option in that case, in addition to the common component, and it can handle creating Deref/DerefMut impls too).
